# Can't receive data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from db and store it in the table im creating below. The thing is there is no error messages, nothing, but also there is no data in the table, but it creates the needed amount of pages - 5 (20 recorded per page - 100 records overall in db)

Here us the code of the page:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "payment";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banks ORDER BY BankName ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql); 

?> 
<table>
<tr><td>BankName</td><td>BIC</td></tr>
<?php 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $row["BankName"]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $row["BIC"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
</table>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(BankName) FROM banks"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

database name:payment

that's how i filled the table 'banks' in mysql

```
DROP TABLE `banks`;

CREATE TABLE `banks` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `BankName` varchar(255),
  `BIC` varchar(34),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Nunc Foundation","HR2868074439590957174"),("Facilisis Associates","SK0278253947289821060238"),("Nulla Interdum Ltd","GR6792877438540758859042158"),("Elit Incorporated","GE15735771537664806694"),("Dui Quis Associates","GI29YOQP779533388384588"),("Odio Aliquam PC","NL04OZOU3039063287"),("Phasellus PC","PS232950361277393433941384172"),("Ante Ipsum Primis LLC","SK6576014828156215265651"),("Sit Amet Risus Corporation","LB38063610008389984423100128"),("Blandit Inc.","CY80746861913710184665395083");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Sapien Nunc Pulvinar Ltd","SE2971469243490215982093"),("Ornare Lectus Justo LLP","PL04638376752565340430115585"),("Eget Consulting","TN2203449817294411776216"),("Diam Dictum PC","SA0707339167762038822862"),("Dolor Tempus Non Institute","AE413237966954343349062"),("Ante Dictum Mi Inc.","SK7166947243639919063650"),("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Corporation","FI0793624922259040"),("Nullam LLC","VG7722649424371381650317"),("Parturient Corporation","SI89446403148884983"),("Orci Corp.","MC8417829370027757931991297");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Ornare Elit Limited","SA3794349239336056649636"),("Nec Institute","AL16499908594511947809642456"),("Auctor Vitae Aliquet Industries","BE97624329404948"),("Proin Vel Consulting","BH73925713986691312360"),("Orci Luctus Et Corporation","DE74563454960683615381"),("Vulputate Nisi LLC","FO3841294839306423"),("Cras Dolor Dolor Foundation","MT78TDWK56103968997690681409041"),("Nec Limited","BG34VSPS18606219365462"),("Nascetur Ridiculus Ltd","CH8256879851538277551"),("Pede Cum Sociis Corp.","FR5277852656716780118772565");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Natoque Penatibus Et PC","BG53AGZP80112721620960"),("Massa Industries","TR582370730215466139565404"),("Donec Limited","BH86705863883792198319"),("Dolor Dolor Institute","DO41796182874282136425851874"),("Sed Libero Proin Associates","CZ5411603519354854012172"),("Consectetuer Cursus Institute","SA3184047665757824177582"),("Dui Semper Et LLC","NL91VMBI3977008594"),("Lacinia LLP","CR6896228497885899082"),("Porta Elit A Foundation","GR5905344924195307758295312"),("Fusce Associates","AD7977722536140145017680");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Nulla Tempor Augue Foundation","DE65842738582539893424"),("Ad Foundation","GB60XIUC88981754591606"),("Laoreet Ipsum Curabitur Incorporated","LU539065698460546129"),("Cras Dictum Ultricies Corp.","SM6752544071539931191353953"),("Nunc Ullamcorper Velit Incorporated","DE76080473329855489301"),("Ipsum Sodales Purus Limited","BA954011780879831971"),("Et Netus Et LLP","IS085559348212680415330861"),("Dui In Associates","LT564586849048032564"),("Ante Ipsum Primis LLP","SK9824408860482038199915"),("Risus Industries","PS664485582535919690570942945");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Rutrum Magna Limited","CR9321843951273249605"),("Eu Nulla At Inc.","DO48619462962071699774338871"),("Tellus Suspendisse Sed PC","LI6204702401609334146"),("Dictum PC","TN9008114906982737846777"),("Velit Pellentesque Corp.","EE737555749626602016"),("Libero Limited","IL392571168065366224090"),("Sociosqu Ad Litora Company","ES9590160897942494878405"),("Magna A Corp.","TR537609348459617242769090"),("Pharetra Incorporated","LI1808297118360563316"),("Molestie Ltd","MC9601753980466785599555790");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Libero Ltd","DO82021067207344015669482920"),("Semper Nam PC","SI92793706437319272"),("Integer Institute","LV82QQBD1054709923536"),("Vivamus LLC","VG8944759754489411018240"),("Vehicula Et Rutrum Incorporated","SI80868635844884022"),("Pharetra Associates","AZ76113716936626872246750053"),("Quis Pede Incorporated","GB33FGDO40967883066200"),("Ante Bibendum Ltd","GR5185826383729198623524298"),("Tellus Corporation","NL52MRNL5251926499"),("Convallis Corp.","PL49420145762522619699045558");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Sapien Nunc Pulvinar Inc.","IL308802410077318513675"),("In Scelerisque Scelerisque Consulting","LV50WHTT7181212076272"),("Ultrices Posuere Cubilia Associates","DK1091333316062458"),("Egestas Company","EE416144892810010696"),("Ante Ipsum Corp.","LT364460001520096925"),("Pede Company","SE6015937436784398888007"),("Sit Corp.","CY77400176876670744746317088"),("Est Mauris Rhoncus Ltd","ES1537073801276806247703"),("Ultrices Institute","RS94954893914518951727"),("Aliquet Ltd","VG3870364935077945164645");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Mauris Nulla LLP","HR5788737956002876474"),("Sit Corporation","BA886525148146712853"),("Nibh Corp.","DE45083668748813483643"),("Vestibulum Ante Institute","DK7150636773062012"),("Risus Quisque Libero Limited","FI8975360634570193"),("Mauris Ut Mi Limited","AZ35021498421240745001948476"),("Erat Associates","LU277349014781574915"),("Dolor Fusce Associates","CR1843988368670463569"),("Blandit Mattis Institute","KW5767276123220327583618914092"),("Eleifend Foundation","GR3906926203690693725383136");
INSERT INTO `Banks` (`BankName`,`BIC`) VALUES ("Vitae Nibh Donec Foundation","MT68VXWJ12775969006616753818202"),("Purus Consulting","SE3354867158473636995460"),("Nunc Incorporated","GI09XEOV082956245073393"),("Pharetra Corp.","LI5077767808089497585"),("Risus Duis A LLP","AT113922582132232306"),("Mauris Integer Sem Corporation","PT83909259409929644376456"),("Aliquam Eros Corp.","NO5699213466185"),("Egestas Lacinia Inc.","AL46878775148957642126532965"),("Amet Corp.","AZ50530093884918356223430348"),("Semper Consulting","AE898696147921384132256");
```

So, i can't see why there is 0 info in the table i'm creating in the page, it gives me 0 errors also.

Comment: Try `<?php echo .....` instead

Comment: have you checked table manually is there data present in table?

Comment: Try <?php echo ..... instead –  AbraCadaver 1 min ago          Thanks man,it worked :D

Comment: You are mixing procedural with OOP,should be  `$connection->query($sql)` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code add php tag in your table.

```
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["BankName"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["BIC"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
```

with

```
while ($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

and

```
<? echo
```

with

```
<?=
```

or

```
<?php echo
```

Comment: yeah, it was only because i was using <? instead of <?php

Answer (score -1):

Just add the debug code at the beginning of your script:

error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

See what errors are displayed.